# PHP error when sending Push Notification to iOS test device

Tags: php, ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I followed the tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1#comments) and get all the provisioning file and iOS code done. I copy the ck.pem and device token correctly to the PHP file. But I got this strange error:

```
➜  SimplePush  php simplepush.php simplepush.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
➜  SimplePush
```

It shows that the connection is fine and deliver is successful but my test device didn't get the notification. I am guessing that the error about the "pdo_pgsql" and the "pgsql". I am only testing this on my local machine and there's nothing to do with a database. I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that you need to recompile the module and PHP with the same versions of PHP.  Did you happen to install one or the other via brew?  rebuilding both PHP and the module will allow you to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for the help! That's exactly what I did. I reinstall PHP and pgsql but I still didn't get rid of the warning. I did this:brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php56   Is that correct? I followed this:http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Yes, that should have done it - especially if you used the same --with-pgsql option in the brew install command.  Perhaps then the issue isn't with php, but with the provisioning setup of your app.  I have written a similar script and I remember a similar issue occured when I had the PHP script using the development certificate when the app went live.  Perhaps a similar crossing of the streams has occured here?  Is there another device you can test with?  Have you attempted to use a third party push provider, like Parse?

Comment: So somehow I got the Push Notification working. I guess it's maybe because I have the app open so the notification didn't pop up. So now I am sure the problem is on the PHP side. I am still confused about how to recompile the PHP or the module since I haven't work with PHP much before. Is the following step correct? ➜ HW03  65brew uninstall php56
➜  HW03  brew uninstall php56
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php56
➜  HW03  brew cleanup
Removing: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php56-5.6.3...
Removing: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/xz-5.0.5.tar.gz...
➜  HW03  brew install php56 --with-pgsql

Comment: Yes, those are the correct steps.  You are also correct that the app will not display a push notification if the app is already open.  I do no believe there is any error at all.  Happy coding :)

Comment: But when I run php on the terminal, the error still shows up for some reason? I am not sure why.

Comment: That's because the error has to do with the module version conflicting with the php version.  It has nothing to do with the ability to send push notifications.  You can turn off these warnings in the php.ini file.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the php.ini file. I think I'll try to fix this bug later. Thank you so much for helping me figure out this problem though!